# % not matching zero or more characters in rule?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

According to the manual on [Defining and Redefining Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) (and if I am reading it correctly):

> ‘%’ character matching any sequence of zero or more characters...

But the following is not matching both `bench.cpp` and `bench2.cpp`:

```
bench%.o : bench%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DCRYPTOPP_DATA_DIR='"$(PREFIX)/share/cryptopp"' -c $<

%.o : %.cpp 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<
```

Here's what I see when running make:

```
$ rm bench*.o
$ make static dynamic cryptest.exe PREFIX=/usr/local
make: Nothing to be done for `static'.
make: Nothing to be done for `dynamic'.
g++ -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c bench.cpp
g++ -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -DCRYPTOPP_DATA_DIR='"/usr/local/share/cryptopp"' -c bench2.cpp
```

Above, both `bench.cpp` and `bench2.cpp` should have `-DCRYPTOPP_DATA_DIR='"/usr/local/share/cryptopp"'`. I also tried using the asterisk (`*`) with no joy.

How do I craft a rule that matches both `bench.cpp` and `bench2.cpp`?

Comment: Well, you could always use `benc%.o : benc%.cpp` and hope you don't have any other sources that match benc*.cpp except `bench.cpp` and `bench2.cpp` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link you provided

> A pattern rule contains the character ‘%’ (exactly one of them) in the
>   target; otherwise, it looks exactly like an ordinary rule. The target
>   is a pattern for matching file names; the ‘%’ matches any nonempty
>   substring, while other characters match only themselves.

So `%` doesn't match empty strings.

> ‘%’ character matching any sequence of zero or more characters...

refers to the definition of `vpath` which is totally different.

I'm afraid you'll have to use `bench1` instead of `bench`. Alternatively you can use macro to defines 2 rules but write it only once.

Comment: Thanks @mb. I had two rules originally, but I was trying to fold them into one rule.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I happened to stumble across the proper section of the documentation on this.

According to [4.4 Using Wildcard Characters in File Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html), I should probably use an asterisk in this case.

And according to Stallman and the GNUMake manual, `%` is not a wildcard for specifying file names:

> A single file name can specify many files using wildcard characters.
>   The wildcard characters in make are ‘*’, ‘?’ and ‘[…]’ ...